# MYSQL WHERE clause, last week year over week

Tags: mysql

I have a portion of a WHERE clause below and I though I had this right but I dont seem to:

```
        AND (WEEK(DeliveryDate, 1) = (WEEK(CURDATE(), 0) - 1))
        AND (YEAR(DeliveryDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())))
```

The way I though this worked according to the documention was that the "1" here `(WEEK(DeliveryDate, 1)'` was telling it to start the week on Monday.  Then the "0" here `= (WEEK(CURDATE(), 0) - 1))` was telling it to start in the week that just ended. This is however not what is happening. Instead this expression is calculating the week the ended November 29th instead of this past week that ended December 6th. What is being missed? [image: a picture of the table results when running with the above WHERE clause]

EDIT 1
The above WHERE clause is what I was told to move to at one point at the suggestion of another user. I had previously been using CURDATE() then the Interval between X and Y to get one week ago, not including this week and not the last 7 days. Here is the result of the folling query:

```
select post_id,DeliveryDate from table where deliverydate >= now() - interval 1 week
```

[image]

Comment: can you explain in English what you want to filter on?  comparing WEEK results passing different modes looks very wrong, as does comparing week and year separately rather than comparing yearweek()

Comment: @user3783243 added. its a very different result

Comment: @ysth, I am pulling the data just for the start of last week until the end of last week with the week starting on Monday. There are a lot of various ways to do this and at one point I was changed over to this, being told it is a better way. See edit 1 above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to see if DeliveryDate is in the previous week, where weeks start on Monday, do:

```
AND YEARWEEK(DeliveryDate, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 1)
```

Adjusting the return of week won't work well across year boundaries, and checking week and year separately can go wrong in a number of ways, and comparing week values using different modes isn't going to do anything useful.

Comment: by goose egg, you mean no results?  works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=6a963c656656d31465b48b990c0f049b